# Why does my code only copy the latest row in the loop as many times as the loop has met the condition, instead of every row that meets the condition

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyRow()
'Declare variables
    Dim sheetNo1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNo2 As Worksheet
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    
'Set variables
    Set sheetNo1 = Sheets("EA Log")
    Set sheetNo2 = Sheets("Commitments")
    
' Define destination sheets to move row
    FinalRow1 = sheetNo2.Range("A" & sheetNo2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
'Apply loop for column P until last cell with value
    For Each Cell In sheetNo1.Range("P4:P" & sheetNo1.Cells(sheetNo1.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
    
'Apply condition to match the "Signed" value
        If Cell.Value = "Signed" Then
        
'Command to Copy and move to a destination Sheet "Commitments"

            sheetNo1.Range(sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 2), sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 3)).Copy _
                        Destination:=sheetNo2.Range("A4:A" & FinalRow1)
                        
            sheetNo1.Range(sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 14), sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 14)).Copy _
                        Destination:=sheetNo2.Range("C4:C" & FinalRow1)
                        
            sheetNo1.Range(sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 1), sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 1)).Copy _
                        Destination:=sheetNo2.Range("E4:E" & FinalRow1)
                        
            sheetNo1.Range(sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 25), sheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 25)).Copy _
                        Destination:=sheetNo2.Range("D4:D" & FinalRow1)
                        
                FinalRow1 = FinalRow1 + 1
                
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
        
  End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the `4` in the `Destination:=` lines is correct. Every time you're overwriting from row 4 to the final row. Should instead be `Destination:=sheetNo2.Range("A" & FinalRow1)` and so on. Also you don't need a loop for this.

Comment: I agree with @BigBen, If `FinalRow1` is something like 50, then your destination is A4:A50, and then A4:A51, and then A4:A52. Each time it is copying values, it is writing the values to the entire destination column, because your destinations are ranges of cells instead of single cells. You probably meant to do just `"A" & FinalRow1` not `"A4:A" & FinalRow1` but there is still a problem with the first copy line. 2 columns of data would be going into a single column of data "B:C" from SheetNo1 going into "A" from SheetNo2.

Comment: @Toddleson - I think those two columns would paste into A and B on SheetNo2, shouldn't be a problem. But the second through fourth `Copy` calls should be probably simplified to `SheetNo1.Cells(Cell.Row, 14).Copy ...` and so on, their setup is overly verbose right now.